# Display categories inline

Tags: categories

how can I show the categories inline in a widget?? I already tried using the wp function wp_list_categories ('style = none') and using the php function str_replace to replace the tags br but without success.
Thanks

Comment: Questions are meant to be references for later visitors as well. Please rework your questions spelling/punctuation/grammar/capitalization so it as as easy to read as possible. Thanks. Aside from that: Please show your actual code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`wp_list_categories ('style = none')`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/wp_list_categories) will `echo` its content as it goes. It won't pass back string that you can replace. You need to use the `wp_list_categories` *filter* to strip the `<br />` tags.

```
add_filter(
  'wp_list_categories',
  function($str) {
    return str_replace('<br />','',$str);
  }
);
wp_list_categories('style=none');
```